# AngularJS $http.Post -> open the urllink + $http.get getting it

Tags: angularjs, http, post, get

im still new with Angular and am trying to grasp the concept.
Currently I cant post code, but this is hopefully not a problem.

I have used https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http  ... especially $http.post in order to Post some data I clicked in the current window

The following Code didnt work due to the error "$http function is not defined", even though $http was already declared... in the correct order I might add (I found other ppl who had issues with that due to the fact that they switched the parameters $scope, $http)
Thats my first Question is there a simple reason? I can add code tomorrow if necessary.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Second Question: Well, but $http.post(..) with parameter url to the second site worked fine.. and in order to use the data i most likely need to use $http.get() at the second site... which I understand.

But how do I need to configure the $http.post that I actually open the url in my browser?

Well I hope you can help me ... sry that I currently can't give you my codeexamples, but I hope it's enough :)

Comment: Did you inject the `$http` service to your function?

Comment: Yes, I have... tried it several ways - especially after reading that on this site ... can show you tomorrow...

Comment: What do you mean by 'that I actually open the url in my browser?' ?

Comment: You also need the `angular-resource` module which contains the http service. Also make sure you load this in your module definition.

Comment: Well... let me explain further... On site "A" I have a list with several items... and if I click on one item in a list  (ng-click=function(item-id,..)  I want to post the data (unique id + type) to site "B" in order to process the data... and I want to open this site "B" with the processed data.. hope you understand my explanation.

Comment: well... I'll try tomorrow... I use the ionic framework ... and in *.run is already $httpsBackend defined ...so I hoped $http would also work

Comment: I think $httpBackend is a different service to $http since $httpBackend is used to mock the $http service.

Comment: As to opening the url in a new window you could do something like this: 
`$window.open(url)`

Comment: Well... but when I open $window.open(url) can  I still access my $http Post data? .. just wondering about the correct chronological order ... in order to GET the POST data...